# Converting an AST to bytecode

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, bytecode, interpreter

So I'm writing a little interpreter in C at the moment for a language I have created (which is pretty similar to Python). I have written the lexer and parser and currently my program outputs an AST, an now I am attempting to turn this AST into bytecode. Currently my algorithm traverses the AST (depth-first) and can generate bytecode for simple arithmetic, and now I am trying to implement if statements.

I cannot copy all my code in here because it's a pretty large amount of code, but currently the program takes an AST which might look something like

```
ADD
|-- 1
|-- MUL
    |-- 2
    |-- 3
```

and turns this into

```
LOAD 1 //the real code doesn't put the value here, but a number representing the position of this value in an array
LOAD 2
LOAD 3
MUL
ADD
```

This is easy for simple expressions but I really don't know how to generate the bytecode for an if statement. I know that I will have to jump  to the else clause if the comparison is false, and also jump from the end of every if/else if block, but how do I deal with this if the jump is more than 256 bytes of bytecode?

Comment: Why is your jump distance limited to 256?

Comment: @usr2564301 because it is bytecode, an each byte is 8bits, allowing 256 bytes to jump over.

Comment: If i use multiple bytes that will waste space for jumps less than 256 bytes

Comment: Not necessarily. Some bytecode are 16 bits.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but then again, if I have less than 256 instructions, which I do, if I use 16bit bytecode I will waste at least 8 bits per instruction

Comment: You are then also limiting yourself to <256 items for all other items – number of literals and variables, number of functions, and so on. I think you may be taking the "byte" in *byte-code* a bit too literal.

Comment: @usr2564301 is there an easy way to make it variable, kind of like unicode?

Comment: ... If you *must*, then "less than 256" should be -128..127. Consider loops! And for larger distances, add more jumps in between. (Whose "size", in turn, you then must include in yet other jumps. Enjoy working that out.)

Comment: @DanielGee: yes, you can have variable-length opcodes or operands. For instance a relative distance of `0` is clearly useless, so you can have the range -128..127 excluding 0, and treat 0 as meaning "read two more bytes to get a 16 bit number". If the first byte of that 16 bits is zero, there was no point in encoding it this way, so you could treat that as a flag meaning "read 3 or 4 bytes to get a 24 or 32 bit number" (depending on whether you think 24 bit numbers are good), and so on. Or, you can just have FARJUMP, etc.

Comment: You may use [an existing bytecode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html) as inspiration…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), then [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces).

I hope you can redesign your bytecode. Then you could have some `FARJUMP` bytecode, which is followed by *four* bytes `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` (considered as `uint8_t` unsigned integers of 8 bits each), for which you'll jump to `(a<<24) + (b<<16) + (c<<8) +d` offset.

You probably want to be able to jump backward and forward. Either have a `BACKFARJUMP` to jump backward, or use some *signed* offset...

With such an opcode, you'll be able to jump to over four billion bytecodes (2<sup>32</sup> exactly). That could be more easy.

If a four billion bytecode offset is not enough, you could generalize.

Don't forget that your computer is unlikely to have more than a terabyte of RAM (and such a computer costs more than a car).

Comment: *Engineering a Compiler* by K. Cooper,‎ and L. Torczon is a great addition to your list too!